# Editing HTML for payment option

Tags: php, opencart

I want to add HTML to a specific input button on the payment page.

```
<?php foreach ($payment_methods as $payment_method) { ?>
<div class="radio">
<label>
  <?php if ($payment_method['code'] == $code || !$code) { ?>
  <?php $code = $payment_method['code']; ?>
  <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo $payment_method['code']; ?>" checked="checked" />
  <?php } else { ?>
  <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo $payment_method['code']; ?>" />
  <?php } ?>
  <?php echo $payment_method['title']; ?>
  <?php if (isset($payment_method['terms']) && $payment_method['terms']) { ?>
  (<?php echo $payment_method['terms']; ?>)
  <?php } ?>
</label>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

So I want to specify, that if payment option is pp_pro_iframe, then add some extra html into this part

```
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="<?php echo $payment_method['code']; ?>" />
```

So it'd end up

```
<input type="radio" name="payment_method" NEW HTML CODE value="<?php echo $payment_method['code']; ?>" />
```

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

/catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/payment_method.tpl lines 11 and 13